When adding planes to my 3D scatter plot, one plane is not shown (Plotly)
I am creating three plots in one HTML file. The third plot is a 3D scatter plot in which I want to add two planes. For a reason the same approach add the second plane but not the first. I though that the second plane overwrite the first but this is not the case.
This is the whole script of my script
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.io as pio
import plotly.graph_objs as go

# Load the merged data
merged_data = pd.read_csv('Merged_Variants_with_TP_FP_and_Data_origin.csv')

# Apply the first filter to select only 'PASS' variants in the 'Original filter' column
filtered_data_original = merged_data[merged_data['Original filter'] == 'PASS']

# Apply the second filter to select only SNPs (where the length of REF and ALT is 1)
filtered_data_original['Mutation_Type'] = filtered_data_original.apply(
    lambda row: 'SNP' if len(row['REF']) == 1 and len(row['ALT']) == 1 else 'indel', axis=1)
filtered_data_original = filtered_data_original[filtered_data_original['Mutation_Type'] == 'SNP']

# Split the 'AD' column into two new columns 'AD_REF' and 'AD_ALT'
filtered_data_original[['Number of REF reads', 'Number of ALT reads']] = filtered_data_original['AD'].str.split(',', expand=True)

# Convert the new columns to integers
filtered_data_original['Number of REF reads'] = pd.to_numeric(filtered_data_original['Number of REF reads'])
filtered_data_original['Number of ALT reads'] = pd.to_numeric(filtered_data_original['Number of ALT reads'])

# Create a new column for the combined TP and Data_origin for the legend
filtered_data_original['Legend_Group'] = filtered_data_original['TP'] + " " + filtered_data_original['Data_origin']
filtered_data_original["MBQ_diff"] = pd.to_numeric(filtered_data_original["MBQ_REF"], errors='coerce') - pd.to_numeric(filtered_data_original["MBQ_ALT"], errors='coerce')
filtered_data_original["MMQ_dif"] = pd.to_numeric(filtered_data_original["MMQ_REF"], errors='coerce') - pd.to_numeric(filtered_data_original["MMQ_ALT"], errors='coerce')

# Filter the DataFrame for additional classification
Detected_False_positive_MBQ = filtered_data_original.loc[
    filtered_data_original['New filter'].str.contains("high_diff_MBQ", na=False)]

Detected_False_positive_MMQ = filtered_data_original.loc[
    filtered_data_original['New filter'].str.contains("high_diff_MMQ", na=False)]

Detected_False_positive = filtered_data_original.loc[
    filtered_data_original['New filter'] != "PASS"]

# Create the first plot: Variant Frequency vs. Difference in MBQ
fig1 = px.scatter(
    data_frame=filtered_data_original,
    x='VF',
    y='MBQ_diff',
    color='TP',
    symbol='Data_origin',
    title="Variant Frequency vs. Difference in MBQ",
    labels={'VF': 'Variant Frequency (VF)', 'MBQ_diff': 'Difference in MBQ (MBQ_diff)'},
    color_discrete_map={'TP': 'green', 'FP': 'red'},
    symbol_map={'Somatic_training_data': 'star', 'Ssrep_training_data': 'circle'},
    hover_data={
        'Sample': True,
        'Chrom': True,
        'Pos': True,
        'REF': True,
        'ALT': True,
        'QUAL': True,
        'Original filter': True,
        'DP': True,
        'VF': True,
        'TP': True,
        'Mutation_Type': True,
        'MMQ_dif': True,
        'MBQ_diff': True,
        'Data_origin': True,
        'Number of REF reads': True,
        'Number of ALT reads': True,
        'New filter': True,
    }
)

# Add the subset (False Positives) to the first plot
fig1.add_trace(px.scatter(
    data_frame=Detected_False_positive_MBQ,
    x='VF',
    y='MBQ_diff',
    color_discrete_sequence=['black'],  # Color the dots black
    symbol_sequence=['circle'],         # Use small dots
    hover_data={
        'Sample': True,
        'Chrom': True,
        'Pos': True,
        'REF': True,
        'ALT': True,
        'QUAL': True,
        'Original filter': True,
        'DP': True,
        'VF': True,
        'TP': True,
        'Mutation_Type': True,
        'MMQ_dif': True,
        'MBQ_diff': True,
        'Data_origin': True,
        'Number of REF reads': True,
        'Number of ALT reads': True,
        'New filter': True,
    },
    size_max=1
).update_traces(marker=dict(size=5, opacity=0.8), name='False Positives').data[0])

# Create the second plot: Variant Frequency vs. Difference in MMQ
fig2 = px.scatter(
    data_frame=filtered_data_original,
    x='VF',
    y='MMQ_dif',
    color='TP',
    symbol='Data_origin',
    title="Variant Frequency vs. Difference in MMQ",
    labels={'VF': 'Variant Frequency (VF)', 'MMQ_dif': 'Difference in MMQ (MMQ_dif)'},
    color_discrete_map={'TP': 'green', 'FP': 'red'},
    symbol_map={'Somatic_training_data': 'star', 'Ssrep_training_data': 'circle'},
    hover_data={
        'Sample': True,
        'Chrom': True,
        'Pos': True,
        'REF': True,
        'ALT': True,
        'QUAL': True,
        'Original filter': True,
        'DP': True,
        'VF': True,
        'TP': True,
        'Mutation_Type': True,
        'MMQ_dif': True,
        'MBQ_diff': True,
        'Data_origin': True,
        'Number of REF reads': True,
        'Number of ALT reads': True,
        'New filter': True,
    }
)

# Add the subset (False Positives) to the second plot
fig2.add_trace(px.scatter(
    data_frame=Detected_False_positive_MMQ,
    x='VF',
    y='MMQ_dif',
    color_discrete_sequence=['black'],  # Color the dots black
    symbol_sequence=['circle'],         # Use small dots
    hover_data={
        'Sample': True,
        'Chrom': True,
        'Pos': True,
        'REF': True,
        'ALT': True,
        'QUAL': True,
        'Original filter': True,
        'DP': True,
        'VF': True,
        'TP': True,
        'Mutation_Type': True,
        'MMQ_dif': True,
        'MBQ_diff': True,
        'Data_origin': True,
        'Number of REF reads': True,
        'Number of ALT reads': True,
        'New filter': True,
    },
    size_max=1
).update_traces(marker=dict(size=5, opacity=0.8), name='False Positives').data[0])


# Create the 3D plot: Variant Frequency vs. Difference in MBQ and MMQ
fig3 = px.scatter_3d(
    data_frame=filtered_data_original,
    x='VF',
    y='MBQ_diff',
    z='MMQ_dif',
    color='TP',
    symbol='Data_origin',
    title="3D Plot: Variant Frequency vs. Difference in MBQ and MMQ",
    labels={'VF': 'Variant Frequency (VF)', 'MBQ_diff': 'Difference in MBQ (MBQ_diff)', 'MMQ_dif': 'Difference in MMQ (MMQ_dif)'},
    color_discrete_map={'TP': 'green', 'FP': 'red'},
    symbol_map={'Somatic_training_data': 'star', 'Ssrep_training_data': 'circle'},
    hover_data={
        'Sample': True,
        'Chrom': True,
        'Pos': True,
        'REF': True,
        'ALT': True,
        'QUAL': True,
        'Original filter': True,
        'DP': True,
        'VF': True,
        'TP': True,
        'Mutation_Type': True,
        'MMQ_dif': True,
        'MBQ_diff': True,
        'Data_origin': True,
        'Number of REF reads': True,
        'Number of ALT reads': True,
        'New filter': True,
    }
)

# Reduce the size of the dots in the main 3D plot
fig3.update_traces(marker=dict(size=3))  # Set the marker size to 3

import plotly.graph_objs as go

# Define the x, y, and z range
x_range = [min(filtered_data_original['VF']), max(filtered_data_original['VF'])]
y_range = [min(filtered_data_original['MBQ_diff']), max(filtered_data_original['MBQ_diff'])]
z_range = [min(filtered_data_original['MMQ_dif']), max(filtered_data_original['MMQ_dif'])]

# Plane at MBQ_Diff = 8.03 (parallel to the XZ plane)
plane1 = go.Mesh3d(
    x=[x_range[0], x_range[1], x_range[1], x_range[0]],  # 4 corners in x
    y=[8.03, 8.03, 8.03, 8.03],  # Constant y for the plane
    z=[z_range[0], z_range[0], z_range[1], z_range[1]],  # 4 corners in z
    opacity=0.5,
    color='red',
    name='Plane MBQ_Diff 8.03'
)

# Plane at MMQ_Diff = 4.58 (parallel to the XY plane)
plane2 = go.Mesh3d(
    x=[x_range[0], x_range[1], x_range[1], x_range[0]],  # 4 corners in x
    y=[y_range[0], y_range[0], y_range[1], y_range[1]],  # 4 corners in y
    z=[4.58, 4.58, 4.58, 4.58],  # Constant z for the plane
    opacity=0.5,
    color='red',
    name='Plane MMQ_Diff 4.58'
)

# Add the planes to the 3D figure
fig3.add_trace(plane1)
fig3.add_trace(plane2)

# Save all plots in the same HTML file
file_path = "combined_plots_with_3d_and_planes.html"
with open(file_path, "w") as f:
    f.write(pio.to_html(fig1, full_html=False))  # First plot without full HTML
    f.write(pio.to_html(fig2, full_html=False))  # Second plot without full HTML
    f.write(pio.to_html(fig3, full_html=True))   # Third plot with full HTML to close the document

Why the first plane is not shown??
EDIT:
This is the 3D plot

The red one is fig3 and the one I have painted is the missing plane I am not able to plot.

It's hard to help without the data to run the code. To check if the issue is really that the second plane (added to the figure) overrides the first one, I would run fig3.add_trace(plane2) before fig3.add_trace(plane1) to see the "override" occurs as well.

The opposite. The one uncommented doesn't generate the plane.

@EricLavault, I have added the image. I hope this helps to understand the issue.

To check wheather this is really an issue of overwriting, just out-comment one of the add_trace-lines. Can each plane be plottet individually?
You could also simplify your question by making it more minimal-example-like (remove the first two figures code, potentially also the HTML stuff; but please verify that your issue still occurs when you simplify your code).

When creating planes and you're not seeing the plane, the issue usually lies with the delauneyaxis. The default is "z". You only have 2 other possible arguments (x or y).
